# Java cannot find symbol with linked list

Tags: java, list

I am trying to ask if a list contains a certain string.

```
public void searchList(Scanner scan, Object list){


    System.out.println("Search for element:\t");
    String p = scan.nextLine();

    if (list.contains(p))
        System.out.println(p + " is in the list");
    else
        System.out.println(p + " is not in the list.");
}
```

I am getting:

```
Prog7Methods.java:23: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method contains(java.lang.String)
location: class java.lang.Object
        if (list.contains(p))
```

I do not understand! I have imported java.io.* and java.util.* how does it not recognize this?

Comment: I am now trying to call search List from another class with pm.searchList(scan, list); I am getting this: MyProgram7.java:53: searchList(java.util.Scanner,java.util.List) in Prog7Methods cannot be applied to (java.util.Scanner,MyList<java.lang.String>) case 3: pm.searchList(scan, list);

Comment: Hi Josh.  Does MyList implement the List interface?  Check out my answer below for some guidance on methods and interfaces and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the list as a List. Instead of

```
public void searchList(Scanner scan, Object list){
```

use

```
public void searchList(Scanner scan, List list){
```

or even better:

```
 public void searchList(Scanner scan, List<String> list){
```

Comment: I am now getting an error when I try to call pm.searchList(scan, list) from another class.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no `Object.contains()` method. Your method signature should probably be `(Scanner, List)` not `(Scanner, Object)`

Answer (score 1):

`list` is a `Object` and `Object` does not have `contains` method. You need to cast it to a `List` first to call `contains` method. Or, you can change the method signature to receive a `List`.

Comment: You can do this `List linkedList = (LinkedList) list;` and call contains method on `linkedList` object. But better practice is to change the method signature to enforce the incoming object to be a `List<String>`. Casting can cause run time exceptions if the incoming object is not a `List` type.

Comment: I am now getting an error when trying to call, please see above

Comment: @Josh How did you declare `List` in your caller class/method. It has to be `List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>` in the caller class.

Comment: MyList<String> list = new MyArrayList<String>(); This is in the class I am trying to call from

Comment: @Josh What are `MyList` and `MyArrayList`. They do not seem to be of type `List`. Declare it like this in the caller class `List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>()` and add strings to this list object, and then call `pm.searchList(scan, list)`. Please take time to read a good tutorial on `Collections` like this one http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/collections/Collection.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a moment to study an [Object](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).  All Java classes are a subclass of Object, and so all Java classes inherit the methods clone(), equals(), finalize(), hashCode(), and so on.

contains() is not in that list of Object methods.  contains() comes from a different place -- an interface called [Collection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).  An interface defines a contract for some class (and all classes are ultimately Objects), that contract being a list of methods that must be implemented.  Collection defines a contains() method, and everything that implements a Collection interface, including any [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)-implementing class, must provide a contains() method.

When you provide a list to your searchList() method, you are passing it through an Object parameter.  That means that within searchList(), the only methods that can be called are the ones defined for Object, even if the list in your call to searchList() really is a list of some sort.  In a sense, your parameter list has "scrubbed out" the list-i-ness of the list parameter.

What you should do, as mentioned already, is change your parameter to Collection or List.  That way, within your searchList() method, the Java compiler knows that the "list" parameter is really a List, and so really has a contains() method.

Note that List is also an interface, and it incorporates the Collection interface by extending it.  So every class that implements the List interface must provide the methods in Collection, as well as the additional List methods.  Should you use List or Collection?  My opinion is to use the least constraining choice.  It seems like your searchList() only uses contains(), so really, it will work on anything that implements Collection, including, for example, [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

So I would rename your method from referring to where you are looking (inside of a list) to what you are looking for (the nextline).

```
public void searchForNextLine(Scanner scan, Collection lines){


    System.out.println("Search for element:\t");
    String p = scan.nextLine();

    if (lines.contains(p))
        System.out.println(p + " is in the collection of lines");
    else
        System.out.println(p + " is not in the collection of lines.");
}
```

Now let's say you've implemented your list with an [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).  Later you change your mind, deciding that a [TreeSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is better.  This searchForNextLine() method will continue to work, because both TreeSet and ArrayList are implementations of Collection.  Better yet, if you decide to roll your own list class (and are sure that you want an actual List, and not some other sort of Collection), then as long as you implement the List interface, you'll be compelled to provide a contains() method (because you'll also be implementing the Collection interface as part of implementing the List interface), and you can pass object of your new class to searchForNextLine(), confident that it will work perfectly fine without any changes at all.

```
public class MyListClass<T> implements List<T> {
  // all the methods required to implement a List interface
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`list` is an `Object` not a `List`. If you think it is a `LinkedList` then change the method signature. If not, make a cast but do an `instanceof`.

Answer (score 0):

Error output of compiler is quite clear. Your list variable is not List type but Object. Object has no method "contains". 
Change

```
Object list
```

to

```
List<String> list
```

or (Java 1.4 and older)

```
List list
```