# Java wont let me call method with list

Tags: java, list

I am trying to call a method from another class with list but it is not letting me.  Here is my call statement:

```
case 2:  pm.displayList(list);
        break;

case 3:  pm.searchList(scan, list);
        break;
```

And here are my methods:

```
public void displayList(List list){
    System.out.print(list);
}
//search for element
public void searchList(Scanner scan, List list){
    System.out.println("Search for element:\t");
    String p = scan.nextLine();

    if (list.contains(p))
        System.out.println(p + " is in the list");
    else
        System.out.println(p + " is not in the list.");
}
```

Here is my error:

```
MyProgram7.java:50: displayList(java.util.List) in Prog7Methods cannot be applied to (MyList<java.lang.String>)
            case 2:  pm.displayList(list);
                                   ^
MyProgram7.java:53: searchList(java.util.Scanner,java.util.List) in Prog7Methods cannot be applied to (java.util.Scanner,MyList<java.lang.String>)
            case 3:  pm.searchList(scan, list);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions expect a `List`, and you're supplying a `MyList<java.lang.String>`. Check that `MyList` implements the `List` interface (I bet it doesn't).

Also, you probably shouldn't be using the raw `List` type; `List<String>` -- or `MyList<String>`, as appropriate -- would be preferable.

Comment: Thank you this helped.  Now when I run the program and try to search for element it prints "Search for element" and then automatically says  "is not in the list". Shouldn't it wait for what I type in?

Comment: @Josh: That's really hard to answer without knowing what's in the list, what value you're supplying to `contains()`, and without seeing the source code for `MyList.contains()` (or preferably to the entire class).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `MyList<T>` class doesn't implement the `List` interface. Of course, you haven't *shown* us `MyList<T>`, but that's what the compiler error suggests.

(As an aside, do your methods really need to take the raw `List` type instead of using generics?)

Comment: What do you mean by your last statement?

Comment: @Josh: Your methods are declared with parameters of `(List list)` instead of (say) `(List<String> list)` or `(List<?> list)`

Answer (score 0):

The code `searchList` is expecting a `List<Object>`, it appears you are passing a `List<String>`. I am assuming that `MyList` implements `List`.

Since both the method expect each element in the list to be a `String`, take `List<String>`

Answer (score 0):

Josh, is this a variation [on your question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918780)?  Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918780/java-cannot-find-symbol-with-linked-list/7919037#7919037) -- you want to make sure that MyList implements the List interface.

```
public class MyList<T> implements List<T> {
  // you will need to provide implementations for all the
  // methods that make up the List interface here in order to make it compile
}
```

If you are struggling with Java interfaces, there are plenty of explanations and tutorials on the Web you can look at (here is [an example](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=331398)).